# Reflect compiled assembly and generate a file as part of the MSBuild process

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

I'm looking to produce a .targets file that I can bundle in a nuget package, which, when the referencing project is built, reflects the compiled assembly and generates a file in the bin folder as part of the build process.

Can this be done? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than generate a .targets file, you could add an [install.ps1](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package#automatically-running-powershell-scripts-during-package-installation-and-removal) to your nuget package, that modifies the csproj file to add a [post build event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293582.aspx). From there you can execute any bundled powershell script, or basic shell commands.